# Alloc or pass a dictionary?

Tags: xcode, memory, nsdictionary

From a memory/coding point of view, is it better to pass dictionaries between controllers or just re-alloc them in the new class?

Comment: It's a dictionary from a plist by the way

Comment: Can you be more specific? You've given us very little to go on. What's in your dictionaries, are they large or small, how many are there, how long do they live, how many controllers are you talking about, ...

Comment: If the dictionary and it's contents are not going to be changed in a way that would cause problems, it's far better, from an efficiency point of view, to pass the dictionary's pointer (and retain it appropriately) than to allocate and copy a new dictionary instance.  In fact, there are very few cases where one would have need to copy an NSDictionary (though one might wish to copy an NSMutableDictionary to guard against it being modified elsewhere).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I thought that may be the way to go but I just wanted to check with others as I'm relatively new to this!

Comment: How do I give positive feedback for your responses?